# Returning an Enumerator as message to exception in Ruby - Junior Dev

Tags: ruby, exception, enumerator

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.  I have the following test that I'm trying to pass, which I cannot change:

```
def test_raising_unordered_enumerator_should_reference_enumerator
  decending_enumerator = 10.downto(1)
  enumerator = CombinedOrderedEnumerator.new(decending_enumerator)

  begin
    enumerator.take(2)
    assert false
  rescue CombinedOrderedEnumerator::UnorderedEnumerator => exception
    assert_equal decending_enumerator, exception.message
  end
end
```

And I've written the following code (the arguments ***args** are always going to be zero or more Enumerator objects):

```
class CombinedOrderedEnumerator < Enumerator
  class UnorderedEnumerator < RuntimeError; end

  def initialize(*args)
    super() do |yielder|
      values = []
      args.each do |arg|
        raise CombinedOrderedEnumerator::UnorderedEnumerator, arg unless arg.each_cons(2).all? { |a, b| (a <=> b) <= 0 }
        arg.each { |x| values.push x }
      end
      values.sort.each { |v| yielder.yield v }
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the test it fails with this message:

```
1) Failure:
test_raising_unordered_enumerator_should_reference_enumerator(CombinedOrderedEnumeratorTest) [combined_enumerator_test.rb:102]:
Expected: #<Enumerator: 10:downto(1)>
Actual: "#<Enumerator:0x007ffae1846d20>"
```

If I inspect the message string in the test (**arg.inspect**), this comes back when I run the test:

```
1) Failure:
test_raising_unordered_enumerator_should_reference_enumerator(CombinedOrderedEnumeratorTest) [combined_enumerator_test.rb:102]:
Expected: #<Enumerator: 10:downto(1)>
Actual: "#<Enumerator: 10:downto(1)>"
```

Finally, If I try to convert the message string to an enumerator using **arg.to_enum** I get the same thing as using just **arg**, as shown in code above.  So how can I transform the message string from the exception to pass the test? or am I doing something wrong?  Thanks a lot!

NOTE: Test must expect an object, not a string.  I cannot change the test.

Comment: The last inspected message string is a string compared to an object.  Expect a string instead and it should match.

Comment: Agree, but what if I have to expect an object? which I do.  Sorry, should have specified that.

Comment: You also stated that you can not change the test, so my comment may be out of scope anyway.

Comment: To be fair, I only added that after you pointed out the obvious. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the behaviour of your exception class:

```
  class UnorderedEnumerator < RuntimeError
    def initialize(message)
      @message = message
    end

    def message
      @message
    end
  end
```